# Chrome with Port forwarding via ssh

Tags: ssh, google-chrome

I'm having problems with some Google Chrome sessions under Ubuntu 16.04. I want to access, with Google Chrome, the web interface of a gitlab instance that I have running at a server that is behind an ssh proxy. First of all: it works. But not quite like I want it. What I did so far is the following:

1) Forward the port with:

```
>>> ssh -D 8090 -N $HOST
```

2) start google-chrome with a separate profile and with the proxy

```
>>> google-chrome --profile-directory="Profile 1" --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:8090" 130.83.24.57:81
```

That works if the window opened in this way is the first and there are no other Chrome windows currently open. As soon as there is another window I get the message

> Created new window in existing browser session.

in the terminal and the traffic seems to be not forwarded. It would be sweet, if it would work also after other windows are opened, such that I don't have to close the session whenever I want to access this.

Does anyone have ideas here? Thanks in advance.

PS: if a solution with a different browser seems better, I'm not hung up on Chrome for that.

Comment: I am not sure I am following here.  You can launch multiple instances of google-chrome-stable just fine where one has the proxy and the other does not.  It is best to open new tabs if you want them forwarded in the proxy then you can drag the tab off as a new instance.  I do this at work all the time.

Comment: How do you open the one with the proxy?

Comment: `nohup google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:${PORT}" & 2>&1>/dev/null` with yours it would be `nohup google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:8090" & 2>&1>/dev/null`

Comment: I actually open a normal Chrome first, then I run that on the command line for the proxy.  That way they are both open.

Comment: tried that and it only works if the window opened this way is the first one. as soon as there is some existing chrome window open, i can't reach the desired webserver.

Comment: Once you have one proxy and one not, you then open new tabs in whatever one you want.  If you need proxy, make sure you open a new tab in that one and not a new window.

Comment: Somehow, the problem persists even when I do it the way you said.

Comment: Ultimately, I ended up using Firefox. Thanks for the help though, greatly appreciated!